# c# using Enterprise-Library

Tags: enterprise-library

How we can pass data table to stored procedure in c# using Enterprise library ?

I am using command
cmd.AddInParameter(objDbCommand, DBAccessDetails.dataTablePrm, SqlDbType.Structured, curatedListprm);
then coming issue as :
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ZAQ' to data type int.

The data for table-valued parameter "@data" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. SQL Server error is: 245, state: 1

Plz tell me what I do and what is issue ?

Comment: can you share some code with us please with what you are trying to achieve

Comment: also, have you created your user defined table type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to have created your user defined table type

```
CREATE TYPE [schema].[tableName] AS TABLE(
table columns and types )
GO
```

then you need to create your stored proc to take the table valued parameted

```
create procedure procName
(
@tvp dbo.tableNamereadonly
)
```

then you need to pass your datatable in via .Net with something like this

```
var param = new SqlParameter("@tvp" Sqldbtype.Structured);
param.Value = {your data table}
```

Comment: @JitenderSharma can you share your code then please and I will see if there is something that you may have missed

Comment: Thanks resolve its 
This issue was at side me.I was not sending complete data table to sp